# При клике по ссылке в навигационной цепочке , скачивается файл с содержимым страницы

Tags: apache, nginx, битрикс

Добрый день! 
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, при переходе в навигационной цепочке по ссылке "каталог" скачивается файл без расширения с содержимым страницы.

Вот пример, http://www.svetomuz.ru/catalog/zvuk/mikrofony/aksessuary_dlya_mikrofonov/hfm010.html если из карточки товара , попробовать вернуться в каталог, то скачается страница. Больше такого эффекта негде нет. И если положить в папку /catalog/ любой файл, то он тоже скачается , но не откроется в браузере.

Недавно на сайте сделали многосайтовость.
 На втором сайте таких проблем нет.

С чем это может быть связанно? Подскажите куда копать. Спасибо.

Comment: Теперь понятно, так называется навигационная цепочка, не связал со сказкой сразу.

Comment: поправил заголовок вопроса.

Comment: это был просто флейм

Comment: Могу сказать, что `Content-Type` неправильный – `application/force-download`. Забавно, что скачивается PHP скрипт.

Comment: Ну выложи код контроллера `/catalog` или что там в битриксе.

Comment: Вообще-то у вас при переходе в каталог из любого места файл скачивается.

Comment: похоже выяснили проблему, связанно с конфигами nginx и работой композита, жду пока системный администратор внесет правки

Comment: Апач тоже используется?

Comment: да, но не силен в конфигурировании серверов,  все  подробности сказать точно не могу.